# In React, how to use FETCH or AXIOS to "POST" data to Google App Script

Tags: reactjs, google-apps-script, cors, http-post, fetch-api

(I'm new to programing. Although I did research for a whole day, I'm not able to manage all the info online and solve the problems by myself. Extremely appreciate for your time.)

I try to "POST" an Object data from a React project to google apps script.

## **Apps Script**

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
Rcm = ss.getSheetByName("Rcm"); // "Rcm"is the name of the sheet

function doPost(e) {
var para = e.parameter, 
method = para.method;

if (method == "write") {
write_data(para);
}

}

function write_data(para) {
var name = para.name,
email = para.email,
wechat = para.wechat;
degree = para.degree;
program = para.program;
Rcm.appendRow([name, email, wechat ,degree ,program]); 
}
```

## **React Component**

In React, I have a set of object data :

```
const contactAll = {
        ...contact, 
        ...{name}, 
        ...{pronoun}, 
        ...{degree}, 
        ...{program}, 
        ...{recommender},
        ...{position},
        ...{organisation},
        ...{profession},
        ...{wording},
        ...{relationship},
        ...{recommend}
    };
```

I write a "post" request to Google Appa Script. I changed the `Content-Type`  from `application/json`  to `text/plain`  to solve the CORS problem. However...

```
    let uri = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfyc....gEOkUE8S42eZ_k5CGVAUQXw/exec";

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleFetch = ( uri , data ) => {fetch( uri , {
        method: "Post",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
        body: JSON.stringify( data )
    }).then(
        ()=>{
            console.log("data added");
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })
    };


    const handleSecSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleFetch( uri , contactAll );
        navigate("/final", { state: { contactAll } });
    }
```

## **Console Output**

I get three errors:

> Access to fetch at 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw...S42eZ_k5CGVAUQXw/exec' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> POST https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwpQ...E8S42eZ_k5CGVAUQXw/exec net::ERR_FAILED 200

> ```
> Second.js:55 Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
>     at handleFetch (Second.js:47:1)
>     at handleSecSubmit (Second.js:62:1)
>     at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
>     at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
>     at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
>     at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
>     at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
>     at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
>     at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
>     at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
> ```

What do I miss or even what part of knowledge should I put my effort in ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When I saw your Google Apps Script, it seems that your `doPost` returns no value. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. So, please modify your Google Apps Script as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your `doPost` as follows.

```js
function doPost(e) {
  var para = e.parameter,
    method = para.method;
  if (method == "write") {
    write_data(para);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done"); // Added
}
```

- When I tested your script, I could confirm that the same error occurred. And also, by this modification, I confirmed that the error was removed.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your Google Apps Script works fine. So, when your Google Apps Script occurs an error, when `fetch` is run, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [createTextOutput(content)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service#createTextOutput(String))